# Make sense of numbers in perf stat output

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, perf

I've been trying to use perf to profile my running process, but I cannot make sense of some numbers output by perf, here is the command I used and output I got:

```
$ sudo perf stat -x, -v -e branch-misses,cpu-cycles,cache-misses  sleep 1
Using CPUID GenuineIntel-6-55-4
branch-misses: 7751 444665 444665
cpu-cycles: 1212296 444665 444665
cache-misses: 4902 444665 444665
7751,,branch-misses,444665,100.00,,
1212296,,cpu-cycles,444665,100.00,,
4902,,cache-misses,444665,100.00,,
```

May I know what event does the number "444665" represent?

Comment: Don't use `-x`, use the default output format with column headers!  It'll be much more clear which columns represent counts for an event over the whole timed interval.  Or at least compare against the without `-x` output to see what matches up.  (`sleep` is not a great choice to profile, it hardly spends any time running so the results are noisier.  Pick somelike like `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'`

Answer (score 3):

`-x` format of `perf stat` is described in [man page of `perf-stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html#CSV_FORMAT), section CSV FORMAT. There is fragment of this man page without optional columns:

```
CSV FORMAT         top

       With -x, perf stat is able to output a not-quite-CSV format output
       Commas in the output are not put into "". To make it easy to parse it
       is recommended to use a different character like -x \;

       The fields are in this order:
       ·   counter value
       ·   unit of the counter value or empty
       ·   event name
       ·   run time of counter
       ·   percentage of measurement time the counter was running

       Additional metrics may be printed with all earlier fields being
       empty.
```

So, you have value of counter, empty unit of counter, event name, run time, percentage of counter being active (compared to program running time).

By comparing output of these two commands (recommended by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065486/make-sense-of-numbers-in-perf-stat-output#comment111529153_63065486))

```
perf stat  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'
perf stat -x \; awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'
```

I think than run time is nanoseconds for all time this counter was active. When you run `perf stat` with non-conflicting set of events, and there are enough hardware counters to count all required events, run time will be almost total time of profiled program being run on CPU. (Example of too large event set: `perf stat -x , -e cycles,instructions,branches,branch-misses,cache-misses,cache-references,mem-loads,mem-stores  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'` - run time will be different for these events, because they were dynamically multiplexed during program execution; and `sleep 1` will be too short to have multiplexing to activate.)

For `sleep 1` there is very small amount of code to be active on CPU, it is just libc startup code and calling syscall `nanosleep` for 1 second (check `strace sleep 1`). So in your output  444665 is in ns or is just 444 microseconds or 0.444 milliseconds or 0.000444 seconds of libc startup for sleep 1 process.

If you want to measure whole system activity for one second, try adding `-a` option of perf stat (profile all processes), optionally with `-A` to separate events for cpu cores (or with `-I 100` to have periodic printing):

```
perf stat -a   sleep 1
perf stat -Aa   sleep 1
perf stat -a -x ,  sleep 1
perf stat -Aa -x ,  sleep 1
```